# Refactor to use Builder pattern or Telescoping constructor pattern

Tags: design-patterns, parameters, constructor, refactoring

According to Effective Java 2ed *Item 2*

> **telescoping constructor pattern**, in
>   which you provide a constructor with
>   only the required parameters, another
>   with a single optional parameter, a
>   third with two optional parameters,
>   and so on, culminating in a
>   constructor with all the optional
>   parameters.

An example of constructors of the class applying this pattern is borrowed from [When would you use the Builder Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)

*code set 1a*

```
Pizza(int size) { ... }        
Pizza(int size, boolean cheese) { ... }    
Pizza(int size, boolean cheese, boolean pepperoni) { ... }    
Pizza(int size, boolean cheese, boolean pepperoni, boolean bacon) { ... }
```

size is a *required* parameter.
cheese, pepperoni, and bacon are *optional* parameters.
Supposing that I would like to provide the constructor like below.

*code set 1b*

```
Pizza(int size) { ... }        
Pizza(int size, boolean cheese) { ... }    
Pizza(int size, boolean pepperoni) { ... }    
Pizza(int size, boolean cheese, boolean pepperoni, boolean bacon, int price, int) { ... }
```

Another example is that

*code set 2*

```
public AttributeKey(String key, Class<T> clazz)
public AttributeKey(String key, Class<T> clazz) 
public AttributeKey(String key, Class<T> clazz, @Nullable T defaultValue, boolean isNullValueAllowed)
public AttributeKey(String key, Class<T> clazz, @Nullable T defaultValue, boolean isNullValueAllowed, @Nullable ResourceBundleUtil labels)
```

The **two latest example** I gave **didn't follow the characteristic of telescoping constructor** as code set 1a did

1. Are code set 1b and 2 included in telescoping constructor? if not, what is it called?
2. Comparing to using Builder Pattern, which one (between Builder and pattern of code set 1a,2) provides more benefits

Comment: both 1b and 2 give compile-time errors, because they have two constructors with identical signatures.

Comment: The other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1953567/632951 will give more info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would go for either the builder or a different mechanism where the caller can pass a collection of toppings.  If you need to validate what toppings are allowed, you can do that in the constructor or the Toppings setter.  The telescoping/chaining constructor approach may require you to add additional constructors in the future to handle additional combinations of toppings, whereas a collection approach will handle any scenario automatically.  I would also avoid having specific properties in the pizza class for different types of toppings.  What if you need to handle extra cheese?   A single `cheese` boolean will not handle that.  The `Topping` class can be a full-fledged object with subclasses, or you could replace it with just a string.

```
public class Pizza
{
    // setters don't have to be private...
    public int Size {get; private set;}
    private List<Topping> toppings {get; private set;}

    public Pizza(int size) : this(size, new List<Topping>()) // call the other ctor with an empty list of toppings
    {
    }

    public Pizza(int size, List<Topping> toppings)
    {
        Size = size;
        Toppings = toppings;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> What is this pattern of constructors'parameters called?

This is not a design pattern per se, but it is a programming technique called constructor chaining.

> Comparing to using Builder Pattern, which one provides more benefits

The same SO question: [When would you use the Builder Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern) that you have borrowed also explains the difference nicely. In short, builder is preferred over constructor chaining as it can result in proliferation of constructors which can become hard to maintain.

Hope that helps.